# Is it possible to upgrade a Mac Powerbook G4 laptop's hard drive to SSD?

Tags: mac, ssd, upgrade, powerbook

I was not sure if the Powerbook laptops accepted SATA drives, am I able to use a SATA SSD on the Mac [Powerbook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerBook) G4?

Comment: Those who downvoted this are encouraged to leave a comment as to why they did.

Comment: Wikipedia article has a nice clear chart that shows hardware specs for powerbook g4, says what drives are compatible: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerBook_G4

Comment: The question is valid due to the appeal of the Powerbook's keyboard form factor over the modern ones. I've had many people ask me about salvaging their Powerbooks due to this, so I'm interested in seeing what the ceiling for upgrading them is.

Comment: @MaQleod The answers provided below already go beyond the level of detail provided in that Wikipedia article.

Comment: Roll back to your original question asking if the G4 can be upgraded to an SSD. The question doesn't work / is partially a statement now.

Comment: Valid or not, some info on the exact model in question would have been nice, as well as some info on what you've already considered/tried.  That'd be my guess as to the down-votes.

Answer (score 4):

I have just installed a SATA SSD in my 2005 PowerBook G4 17" 1.67GHz running 10.5 Leopard. It is not straightforward swap because you need an adapter which will not fit in the drive bay with a conventional 2.5" laptop drive. mSATA SSdrives are now available and they are tiny. BUT they have a different physical interface to regular SATA - much smaller.

I used an mSATA SSD with an mSATA to SATA converter board and a SATA to IDE converter. I had to cut down the mSATA board so it would fit in the bay - possible because some of the wafer had no circuitry.

The drive was recognized by Disk Utility and I was able to format it APM HFS+ Journaled.

Comment: That looks like a *lot* of work for a nearly decade old system - and curiously interesting. Some pictures might turn this answer into something epic - heck, I'd even bounty that. I'm curious, I want to see the goods!

Answer (score 3):

Powerbook G4's did not support SATA. They used ATA (IDE) drives. The only way to use a SATA drive with it would be to put it in a USB enclosure, or to find an ATA/PATA compatible SSD. Other than that, you would need to get a MacBook to start using SATA.

Comment: ... or buy a PATA compatible SSD?

Comment: @slhck I didn't think it existed! Added to my answer

Answer (score 3):

There are IDE SSDs, therefore you can upgrade your Powerbook G4.

Keep in mind you will get nowhere near the speed of an SSD using SATA.

[32GB IDE SSD on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000T9QRKE) 
[128GB IDE SSD on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00295P40U) - this one is $370, I would start looking at a new / used macbook

Comment: But these would still be a significant improvement over the 5400 rpm drives?

Comment: 2-3x the speed... they would saturate the PATA bus. A 5400 RPM drive at PowerBook G4 vintage would be 40-50 MB/s, the PATA bus on his notebook theoretically goes up to 133 MB/s, so there would be a significant benefit.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure all PowerBook G4's were PATA (Ultra 100 and 133).

This doesn't prevent you from getting and SSD, as there are [PATA SSD drives](http://www.kingspec.com/solid-state-disk-products/ssd-25pata-mlcj.htm) out there, but they're getting harder and harder to find.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible, and I am attempting to do exactly that at the present moment, in 2019, for a computer that was manufactured in March of 2003. You will need to purchase a case that fits the old hard drive space, and then you can easily find an MD-2 type SSD that will screw into that case which will then adapt it to the IDE interface that this laptop accepts. I am awaiting the purchase of an SSD drive from China that will fit the connections and the space. When that arrives, I will reassemble the laptop and let you know if it works. This will replace the older IDE Fujitsu drive at 80GB that did not last very long.

Comment: While you seem to have presented some useful information here, it seems somewhat speculative.  It would have been better if you had waited until you had finished the project and could make more definitive statements.  If you learn anything from your adventure, please come back and [edit] your answer to make it more complete. … … … … … … … … … … … … … P.S. If you’re just now replacing a hard drive that was manufactured in March of 2003, that’s not too shabby.

Comment: This will be the second hard drive replacement. The first upgrade was a conventional hard drive from Fujitsu - 80 GB size from the original 40 GB.